# Google not following "canonical" directive for a certain type of URLs

Tags: seo, google

a few months ago we set up canonical URLs for many page types such as http://www.wowhead.com/item=50362/deathbringers-will. This worked very well and google picked them all up.

A few days ago I implemented the same thing for blog posts but mysteriously it's not working.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/blog=174055/cataclysm-beta-patch-build-13316" />
```

This blog post was written **after** my change but [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=871&q=Cataclysm+Beta+Patch+%28Build+13316%29&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) shows `www.wowhead.com/blog=174055` as the URL; any reason why? I can't really figure it out, the content of the pages is the same, and it's not really any different than what we did with /item and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root-relative `canonical` URL looks funny to me. I'm inclined to include your domain name there. [Google says](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394):

> The `rel="canonical"` attribute can be
>   used with relative or absolute links,
>   but we recommend using absolute links
>   to minimize potential confusion or
>   difficulties. If your document
>   specifies a base link, any relative
>   links will be relative to that base
>   link.

I would be hesitant to judge how Google is indexing until a good amount of time has passed. How old is that url?

Comment: it happens on all NEW blog posts, even if they are only minutes old. We use relative paths for all other page types and it has always worked.

Comment: And have you tested using absolutely links for any posts? I'd say test that.

Comment: I didn't and it would be very complex to do; since relative URLs work for all other page types I don't see why it would be the problem =(

Comment: Well, your answer to the problem is that Google is not working as expected. If you want to see if it might make a difference, you'll have to test it. :-|

Comment: This seems to have worked; thanks. It's still very weird because pages like http://www.wowhead.com/item=2454 use and have always used relative URLs and always worked. :S

Comment: Awesome! Glad it solved your problem. I wonder if Google should amend their recommendation to say "just use absolute links, dudes." :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using absolute versus relative URLs and giving it a bit of time should ... er, actually does work.

http://www.google.com/search?q=Cataclysm+Beta+Patch+%28Build+13316%29

Google is presenting your canonical URL.